# How do we calcualte $E[W_sW_t|W_s]$

Tags: stochastic-calculus

$W_t$ is a Brownian motion. How do we calculate this expectation? 
there are two cases:

1. $s < t$
2. $t < s$

Do we have to distinguish the two cases or there is a unified way of calculating it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $s<t$, then
\begin{align*}
E\big(W_sW_t \,|\, W_s\big) &= W_sE\big((W_t-W_s + W_s)\,|\,W_s\big) \\
&=W_s^2.
\end{align*}

For $0 < t < s$, then $$E\left(W_s \Big(W_t-\frac{t}{s}W_s\Big) \right)= 0,$$ and, given their joint normality, $W_s$ and $W_t-\frac{t}{s}W_s$ are independent.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E\big(W_sW_t \,|\, W_s\big) &= W_sE\left(\Big(W_t-\frac{t}{s}W_s +\frac{t}{s} W_s\Big)\,|\,W_s\right) \\
&= \frac{t}{s} W_s^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: I thought $W_t$ is $F_s$ measurable if $s>t$. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Sanjay: $W_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_s$ measurable if $s>t$, but not $\sigma(W_s)$ measurable. That is, $E(W_t \,|\, W_s) \ne W_t$.

Comment: Ok. I have learned stochastic calculus before proper training in measure theory (and sigma algebra). Sometimes this fact bites me in the a** :D Thanks for clarification